# ¿Por qué no se recarga la búsqueda inicial al estar en input text vacío?

Tags: php, sql

La página lo que hace es ejecutar una instrucción SQL y cargar una serie de registros al entrar en la página. Una vez dentro de la misma, hay un pequeño buscador que permite buscar por EDAD. La búsqueda la realiza perfectamente. Mi problema es que cuando no hay ningún valor en el input text del buscador, no sé porque on me recarga la búsqueda inicial. A ver si alguien me puede dar algo de luz sobre el asunto.

/* FICHERO INDEX.php */

```
<div class="container">       
    <div>
       <table>
            <tr width="100px">
               <form name="Registro" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">                        
               <b>Fab #: </b><input type="text" id="campo" name="campo">
               <input class="agregar" type="submit" value="Buscar">                                       
               </form>                    
               </td>
               <tr></tr>                  
            </tr>
       </table>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <table width="1050px" align="left">
            <tr>
                <th width="45px">Edad</th>    
                <th width="100px">Nombre</th>
                <th width="100px">Apellidos</th>
                <th width="150px">email</th>
                 
            </tr>                     
            <?php include("LeerDatos.php"); ?>       
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

/* FICHERO Leer.php */

```
<?php 
/* Archivo carga la tabla inicial y realiza la búsqueda*/

    require ("miconexion.php");
    
if(empty($_POST)){    
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM alumnos ORDER BY Apellidos DESC LIMIT 5";
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    mysqli_data_seek($resultado, 0);

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        extract($fila);
        echo "    
            <tr>        
                <td align='center'>$Edad</br></td>        
                <td align='center'>$Nombre</br></td>
                <td align='center'>$Apellidos</br></td>
                <td align='center'>$email</br></td>                    
            </tr>";
        }    
}
else{    
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];      
    if (!empty($valor)){
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE Edad = $valor";
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    mysqli_data_seek($resultado, 0);
            
            extract($fila);
            echo "
                <tr>        
                    <td align='center'>$Edad</br></td>        
                    <td align='center'>$Nombre</br></td>
                    <td align='center'>$Apellidos</br></td>
                    <td align='center'>$email</br></td>
               </tr>";                      
        }
    }

mysqli_close($miconexion);

?>
```

Comment: Y el fichero **leer.php** solo hace algo? Si ingresas directamente a el.

Answer (score 0):

Falta una condición para cuando el campo Edad está vacío y se pulsa el botón BUSCAR. En el fichero index.php hay que añadir la propiedad "name='submit'" al input, con lo que quedaría

```
<input name="submit" class="agregar" type="submit" value="Buscar">
```

y en el fichero "Leer.php" se le añade la condición if y quedaría como sigue:

```
<?php 
/* Archivo carga la tabla inicial y realiza la búsqueda*/

    require ("miconexion.php");
    
if(empty($_POST)){    
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM alumnos ORDER BY Apellidos DESC LIMIT 5";
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    mysqli_data_seek($resultado, 0);

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        extract($fila);
        echo "    
            <tr>        
                <td align='center'>$Edad</br></td>        
                <td align='center'>$Nombre</br></td>
                <td align='center'>$Apellidos</br></td>
                <td align='center'>$email</br></td>                    
            </tr>";
        }    
}
else{    
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];      
    if (!empty($valor)){
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE Edad = $valor";
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    mysqli_data_seek($resultado, 0);
            
            extract($fila);
            echo "
                <tr>        
                    <td align='center'>$Edad</br></td>        
                    <td align='center'>$Nombre</br></td>
                    <td align='center'>$Apellidos</br></td>
                    <td align='center'>$email</br></td>
               </tr>";                      
        }
    }

mysqli_close($miconexion);

?>
```